Java FTPs client lib connects to the server successfully but the list of directories is empty with an error with FileZilla servers
I’m using java commons-net client lib to connect to FTPs servers, I can connect with servers successfully. Still, when calling “ftps.listDirectories()” I get “0” when connecting with FileZilla servers with errors:

Error while transferring data: PROT C is not allowed when the control connection is secure. Use PROT P. -> If didn’t use ftps.execPROT(“P”);
Error while transferring data: TLS session of data connection not resumed. ->  If did use ftps.execPROT(“P”);

This issue doesn’t occur with all FTPs servers.
I have tried to create FTPs server locally but I have noticed the following while trying to connect:

FileZilla server's old version (v0.9.60.0) can connect and can “ftps.listDirectories()” if “force PROT to encrypt file transfares when using FTP over TLS” is unchecked.
FileZilla server's new version (v1.8.2.0) only connects but can’t “getListDirectories()”, always empty with the errors I mentioned above.

Please note I have tried the FileZilla client version (v3.67.1) to make sure I can connect to FTPs servers and explore files/directories without any problems.
// To Connect with FTP/s Servers (but no issue with connection at all)
        public FTPConnection(String host, String username, String password, boolean passive) throws IOException {
            if (ftps) {
                this.log = Logger.getLogger(host);
                this.host = host;
                this.clientFtps = new FTPSClient(false);
                try {
                    this.clientFtps.connect(host);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug(e.getStackTrace());
                }
                if (username != null)
                    try {
                        if (pasv) {
                            this.clientFtps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                        } else {
                            this.clientFtps.enterLocalActiveMode();
                        }
                        this.clientFtps.login(username, password);
                        //log.debug(this.clientFtps.getReplyString());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                this.clientFtps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                this.clientFtps.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                log.debug("the type of ftp file is : " + FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            } else {
                this.host = host;
                this.log = Logger.getLogger("ftp://" + host);
                log.debug("ftp://" + host);
                this.client = new FTPClient();
                this.client.connect(host);
                if (username != null)
                    try {
                        this.client.login(username, password);
                        log.debug(this.client.getReplyString());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                this.client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                this.client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                log.debug("the type of ftp file is : " + FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                if (pasv)
                    this.client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                else
                    this.client.enterLocalActiveMode();
            }
        }

// To explore files/directories (here's the problem)
            public String[] dirs() throws IOException {
            if (ftps) {
                FTPFile[] files = clientFtps.listDirectories();
                if (files == null)
                    return new String[0];
                String[] result = new String[files.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                    result[i] = files[i].getName();
                return result;
            } else {
                FTPFile[] files = client.listDirectories();
                if (files == null)
                    return new String[0];
                String[] result = new String[files.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                    result[i] = files[i].getName();
                return result;
            }
        }

